# Configure utm_campaign in Parameter Manager

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloud

I want to configure the utm_campaign in Parameter Manager to be auto-completed and don’t need to add it manually for each campaign, but the only way I found to do it is by using the email name as value. I would like to use something else, because one campaign can have different emails and I don’t want to have different utm_campaign. Any idea of how can I solve it? Is there any way I can use the journey name for example?

Thanks!

Comment: "I would like to use something else" is a very broad definition. You can use any combination of [personalisation strings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) or ampscript variable in your email, to populate the utm_campaign value in Parameter Manager

Comment: If you're happy not to reuse emails between journeys, you can start out by looking at AMPScript, how to embed it in templates and its Data Extension Lookup functions. Then look at the _Job Data View, the _JourneyActivity Data View and the _Journey Data View... They're relatable using the email id of the current send and an associated triggered send object id (the first you come across). Then look at the  AMPScript TreatAsContentArea function to make the whole thing scalable.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen an identifier for Journey Name as such. But if parameter management is enabled for the account (which I am guessing would be enabled) you could use the [Additional Email Attributes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380187&type=1) at the Email level. You could hardcode some of the additional email attributes as the journey name and use that attribute in the Parameter management.